# How to stop event capturing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

We can use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) for stopping event bubbling. Can we use same method for stopping event capturing also?

If no how can we achieve it?

Answer (score 13):

If a listener has been added to the *capturing* phase, rather than the *bubbling* phase, then you can prevent the event from capturing down to child elements with the same method: `event.stopPropagation()`.

For example, in this code, you'll see that `#inner`'s listener is never triggered, because `#outer`'s listener stops the event from propagating downward:

```js
document.querySelector('#outer').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function(event) {
    console.log('propagation stopped');
    event.stopPropagation();
  },
  true // Add listener to *capturing* phase
);

document.querySelector('#inner').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function(e) {
    console.log('inner clicked');
  }
);
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  outer
  <div id="inner">
    inner
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -5):

You should pass `false` as the third argument to the function addEventListener().
This disables the event capturing stage.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', onClickFunc, false);
```

Comment: this is introduced by google as a spoiling commonly used method code